# input type="number" be a 3 digit number or a 8 digit number

Tags: html

Is it possible to limit the number of digits that a user can into a field. E.g.

- For a 3 digit number 184 only
- For a 8 digit number 18875264 only

Comment: To answer the question as asked, yes. It is possible.

Comment: There is a `max` attribute on number inputs, you could (and should) also check it with JS.

Comment: You can add validation to it to make sure it is valid, there is no way to just force 3 or 8.

Comment: You have to use javascript because the input pattern validation is not applied to number input types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 introduced a new attribute for `input` tag - [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern). You can specify the regex as value of pattern attribute to validate the input.

`pattern` does not work with `type="number"` so I'll use `type="text"` instead. `type="tel"` will also work but don't use it unless you really want to input a telephone number.

```html
<form>
  <label for="num-input">3 or 8 digit number: </label>
  <input id="num-input" 
         type="text"
         required
         pattern="\d{3}|\d{8}" 
         title="must be 3 or 8 digit"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The regex `\d{3}|\d{8}` matches 3 digit number or 8 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic HTML-only way of limiting it to three digits would be:

```
<input type="number" max="999" min="-999" />
```

However, this won't force the `max` or `min` attributes when the user inputs a value by hand instead of using the add or substract buttons of the input. To validate that, you'd need to add some javascript that checks the users input:

```
document.querySelector('input[max], input[min]').onblur = function (event) {
  const numValue = Number(event.target.value);
  // if within the expected range, do nothing
  if (numValue  < event.target.max && numValue  > event.target.min) return;
  // check if it's closer to max than to min,
  // then set the value to max or min accordingly
  event.target.value = event.target.max - numValue  < event.target.min - numValue  ?
    event.target.max :
    event.target.min;
}
```

#### Update

Upon further inspection, I realized I had misunderstood the question.

In order to allow only three or eight digit numbers, you could use the following validation:

```js
document.querySelector('input').onblur = function (event) {
  let valString = Number(event.target.value).toString();
  if (valString.length === 3 || valString.length === 8) return;
  event.target.value = valString.length > 8 ?
    valString.substr(0, 8) :
    (valString.length > 3 ? valString.substr(0, 3) : null);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

This will trim any value longer than eight digits to eight, trim any value longer than 3 but shorter than eight digits to three, and leave blank if 1 or 2 digit values are inputted.

Comment: How would this limit them to ### or ########?

Comment: @epascarello my bad, I had misunderstood it as meaning "how to limit to a max of N digits", not how to limit to two different specific digit ammounts.